# How to compare first and last index of a string in a list

Tags: python, string, list

input :`['slx', 'poo', 'lan', 'ava', 'slur']`
output:`['s', 'o', 'l', 'a', 'r']`
how do you compare the first and last index of a string in a list?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the logic to this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you mean?

Comment: for eg 'slx' it will output s as s<x and 'poo' it will output o as o<p,I'm only considering the first and last element inside my string and output the smaller one then put them in a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to compare the characters and get the 'smaller' one (lexicographically). You can use list comprehension and `min` for that:

```py
lst = ['slx', 'poo', 'lan', 'ava', 'slur']
output = [min(x[0], x[-1]) for x in lst]
print(output) # ['s', 'o', 'l', 'a', 'r']
```

Comparing two strings is done lexicographically: for example, `'banana' < 'car' == True`, since "banana" comes before "car" in a dictionary. So for example, `'s' < 'x'`, so `min('s', 'x')` would be `'s'`, which explains the first element of the output list.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = ['slx', 'poo', 'lan', 'ava', 'slur']
print(list(map(lambda x: min(x[0], x[-1]), s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to find the smallest value (compared between first and last character) from a string inside a list:

to do this

```
list = ['slx', 'poo', 'lan', 'ava', 'slur']
result=[]

for item in list:
    leng = len(item)
    if item[0] < item[leng-1]:
        result.append(item[0])
    else:
        result.append(item[leng-1])
print(result)
```